# Associating users with models django

Tags: python, django

I have a lot of models in model.py -

```
class Portfolio(models.Model):
  company = models.TextField(null=True)
  volume = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
  date = models.DateField(null=True)
  isin = models.TextField(null=True)

class Endday(models.Model):
  company = models.TextField(null=True)
  isin = models.TextField(null=True)
  eop = models.TextField(max_length=100000)

class Results(models.Model):
  companies = models.TextField(default=0)
  dates = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
  eodp = models.FloatField(null=True)
  volume = models.IntegerField(null=True)

class Sectors(models.Model):
  sector_mc = models.TextField(null=True)

class Insector(models.Model):
  foundation = models.ForeignKey(Sectors, null=True)
  name = models.TextField(null=True)
  value = models.FloatField(default=0)

class AreaLineChart(models.Model):
  foundation = models.ForeignKey(CompanyForLineCharts, null=True)
  date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
  price = models.FloatField(null=True)

  class Meta:
    ordering = ['date']
```

I have more such models but as you can see from this snippet, they are not in any way related to any user.

Now I want to relate them to a particular user. In the views too, I was not classifying data per user in any way.

I make users from django admin with username and password and also generate a token for those users from admin. I can authenticate via username and password but from there I know I'd need to use permissions but how is what I do not know. Also, I have serializers that are associated to these models, I know I'd have to use permissions there too but again, I don't know how to. As much as I understand it has to be in someway like this-

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def searched_company_ohlc(request):
  if request.method == 'GET':

  // User.objects.get('username'=some_user) 
  //I guess.

  qs = SearchedCompanyOHLC.objects.all()
  serializer = SearchedCompanyOHLCSerializer(qs, many=True)
  return Response(serializer.data)
```

Also, I'm using angularJS at the front-end that POSTS `username` and `password` on a view with `POST` decorator to verify the credentials. Where to go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your models.py you can relate user like this for example

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import  User, Group
class Portfolio(models.Model):
 owner = models.ForeignKey(User,verbose_name = 'User',related_name='portfolios')
 company = models.TextField(null=True)
 volume = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
 date = models.DateField(null=True)
 isin = models.TextField(null=True)
```

Comment: I have to associate other models too, the same would go for all of them?

Comment: Also, the process flow would be like, first I authenticate the user, next I run the functions in the view and while saving, provide the user object too, third when I write an api to serve data, I do as written above in the question?

Comment: you must assign the relationship between tables for example  1 user has 1 portfolio or many.  You can refer to this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey  see what relationship do you need and the via django rest and angular you can get related items

Comment: User has one portfolio but all the other tables are also associated to that user only, that is why the question

Comment: if other tables don't relate to portfolio then you have to add the User to other tables as Foreign Key as well

Comment: Thanks. Also, the second comment?

Comment: you can refer to django rest tutorial on how to filter you api view with logged user http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123533/discussion-between-thatbird-and-dimitris).

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with permissions.

If you want to associate your model with a user, use a ForeignKey to the user model.